# Using Grails/Spring Web Flows in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails, spring-webflow

What's the best way to handle a conversation-based web flow in Rails? I'm wondering if there is anything similar to http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/single.html#6.5%20Web%20Flow

---

A web flow is a conversation that spans multiple requests and retains state for the scope of the flow. A web flow also has a defined start and end state.

Web flows don't require an HTTP session, but instead store their state in a serialized form, which is then restored using a flow execution key that Grails passes around as a request parameter. This makes flows far more scalable than other forms of stateful application that use the HttpSession and its inherit memory and clustering concerns.

Web flow is essentially an advanced state machine that manages the "flow" of execution from one state to the next. Since the state is managed for you, you don't have to be concerned with ensuring that users enter an action in the middle of some multi step flow, as web flow manages that for you. This makes web flow perfect for use cases such as shopping carts, hotel booking and any application that has multi page work flows.

Answer (score 0):

I just started looking into this question myself, but from the perspective of DRYing up view code.  Not finding much, but there is:

https://github.com/jcoglan/action_flow      which may take some rejigging for newer Rails

http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=2769     which has no docs and looks alpha

The age and activity levels on each project lead me to believe they've been abandoned.

Wiring up flows as point-to-point links of imperative calls with routes/controllers/actions/views that make fixed assumptions about where they fall in the chain (or worse, entrain lots of conditionals to deal with different flows), is certainly one way I've seen it done. Still wondering if that is the preferred stock in trade in the Rails world, or if there are other idioms that supplant it that I just don't know about.